# How can I pass string slices into Kingpin?

Tags: go, command-line-arguments

Here's the minimal example:

```
import "gopkg.in/alecthomas/kingpin.v2"
...
fooCodes = kingpin.Flag("foo_codes", "List of codes").Default().Strings()
```

and I tried passing `--foo_codes=AA,BB,CC` that didn't work unfortunately so I had to use

```
--foo_codes=AA
--foo_codes=BB
--foo_codes=CC
```

instead as a workaround (I'm passing those `args` in a yaml file. Is there a better option that I can configure via `kingpin`?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use `HintOptions` or `HintAction`, for more details see these examples: https://github.com/alecthomas/kingpin/blob/master/_examples/completion/main.go